# No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish

I am trying to persist a user input ( a question :its id is an auto generated value) but i am getting this exception`No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long`.

This is the code of the jsf page

```
            <p:panel style="margin-left:30%">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="grid">
                <h:form id="form">
                    <h3>Titre</h3>
                    <p:inputText placeholder="Donner un titre significatif" size="56" value="#{questionBean.newQuestion.titre}"></p:inputText><br/>
                        <p:editor id="editor"  width="600"  value="#{questionBean.newQuestion.contenu}"/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:10px">
                            <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Poser Question" action="#{questionBean.create}"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
```

and this is the code of the managedBean

```
                         import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
             import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
             import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
             import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
             import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
              import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
             import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
                 import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

      import com.portail.dao.DaoQuestion;
      import com.portail.entities.Question;
      @ManagedBean(name="questionBean")
     @SessionScoped
      public class QuestionBean implements java.io.Serializable {
private List<SelectItem> questItems;
private DataModel questions;
private List<Question> questionsEtudiant;
private List<Question> questionsProfesseur;
private Question newQuestion= new Question();
private Question editQuestion;
private List<Question> questionsForums;
private List<Question> questionssansreponses;
private DaoQuestion qDao=new DaoQuestion();
    public String create(){
    qDao.ajouter(newQuestion);
    newQuestion= new Question();
    System.out.println("question ajouter ");
    questions.setWrappedData(qDao.selectAll());
    return"list";
}
```

And this is the code of the entity

```
              @Entity(name="Question")
      @Table(name="QUESTION")
    @NamedQuery(name="Question.findAll", query="SELECT q FROM Question q")
     public class Question implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_ques",sequenceName="SEQ_PK_QUES",initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
@Id
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seq_ques")
@Column(name="QUES_PK")
private long quesPk;
    @Column(length=200)
private String contenu;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date datecreation;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateedition;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date datemodification;

private int nbdownvote;

private int nbupvote;
    @Column(length=300,unique=true)
private String titre;
```

And this is the code of the DAO class used to persist the question

```
                   public class DaoQuestion {
private static final String JPA_UNIT_NAME="Portail";
private EntityManager entityManager;
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (entityManager == null) {
        entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                JPA_UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager();
    }
    return entityManager;
}

 public   void ajouter(Question q)
    {
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        entityManager.persist(q);
        tx.commit();

    }
```

Comment: Do you have hibernate-validator.jar file?

Comment: I am using the default implemntation to persist the data. do i have to download that jar too?

Comment: It is just a guess. I had a somewhat similar problem some time ago. Download this file and put in your build path. A complete name of this file will look something like this hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar

Comment: ok i will try and see if it solves my problem

Comment: No adding that jar don't solve the problem

Comment: Can you remove the @NotNull from your field quesPk and check if it works just for debugging purpose?

Comment: I removed it and the problem is still there

Answer (score 3):

As per the hibernate api for @NotNull annotation, [@NotNull](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/NotNull.html) only applies to String. With that being said, make sure the @NotNull annotation you're using is from `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` and not a Hibernate annotation.

If you hover over @NotNull in your code, it should tell you whether it's from hibernate or javax.

A similar post, you may want to look at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982741/error-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type-java-lang-integer)